# SQLAlchemy ignoring specific fields in a query

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy with Flask to talk to a postgres DB. I have a Customer model that has a `date_of_birth` field defined like this

```
class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'customer'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_of_birth = Column(Date)
```

Now, I am trying to filter these by a minimum age like this:

```
q.filter(date.today().year - extract('year', Customer.date_of_birth) - cast((today.month, today.day) < (extract('month', Customer.date_of_birth), extract('day', Customer.date_of_birth)), Integer) >= 5)
```

But the generated SQL seems to ignore the `day` part and replace it with a constant. It looks like this

```
SELECT customer.date_of_birth AS customer_date_of_birth,
FROM customer
WHERE (2017 - EXTRACT(year FROM customer.date_of_birth)) - CAST(EXTRACT(month FROM customer.date_of_birth) > 2 AS INTEGER) >= 5
```

The generated SQL is exactly the same when I remove the `day` part from the query. Why is sqlalchemy ignoring it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're comparing two `tuple`s:

```
(today.month, today.day) < (extract('month', Customer.date_of_birth), extract('day', Customer.date_of_birth))
```

The way tuples compare is, compare the first element, and if they're not equal then return the result, otherwise return the comparison of the second element. So, in your case, it's the same as comparing the first elements together.

Instead of two `tuple`s, what you should compare is the [`tuple_`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.tuple_) construct, like this:

```
(today.month, today.day) < tuple_(extract('month', Customer.date_of_birth), extract('day', Customer.date_of_birth))
```